# jquery page history and loads container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am designing an ecommerce website. i used a jquery page loading script for load pages without page refresh. the code is below-

```
var trigger = $('.hyperlinks'),
    container = $('.main-wrapper');

       trigger.on('click',function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       var target = $this.data('target');

       container.load(target);

       return false;
     });
```

well

site structure is looks like

```
<header>
    <a class="hyperlinks">a link</a>
    <a class="hyperlinks">a link</a>
</header>
<div class="main-wrapper">Contents and links with class hyperlinks also</div>
<footer></footer>
```

well above script is works for header links but not for main-wrapper links if any available of class .hyperlinks

also when i load a links of header with above script main-wrapper updates but i need some suggestion to page refreshe. because to refresh a page, my site re navigates to index.php not on the page on which i was currently also browser back and forward button do the same thing which is a problem.

help to resolve me this isssue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your links inside **main-wrapper** are loaded via ajax and do not exists in the time when the click event is binded.

You need to update your code:

```
container = $('.main-wrapper');

$('body').on('click', '.hyperlinks', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.data('target');

    container.load(target);

    return false;
});
```

Instead of **body**, you can use any other tag that surrounds all `.hyperlinks`. But in case of your code above, the body will work.

Comment: i understood what this change will do. it binds all .hyperlinks links of the body to work with the script. i thinks i will help. thanx

Comment: what will i do for saving history when i clicked on a link. because, here is another problem that is when i clicke on a link and contents loads by AJAX. the page GET URL is always show index.php and when i refresh the page then again my page shows the contents of index.php. so, i always try my website again and again from index.php for testing.

Comment: @ShahzadAshrafi - you can change your location hash. When someone clicks on `.hyperlinks` you just change your url to `index.php#subpage`(**subpage** si the string from data-target). Then you bind ajax loading on hashchange. Google it, there are plenty of tutorials on web. Here is [one example](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/).

Comment: thanks for help, i changed my js code and used location hash and also used page cache by souce code copied from the webpage https://github.com/curran/screencasts/blob/gh-pages/navigation/examples/code/snapshot23/navigation.js

Comment: but here is a problem that when i open #signup which contains a <div> inside which i applied designing for signup for and provided each input a seprate id and also applied an internal js code for fetching errors from process.php using ajax. when i clicked on #submit nothing happens also i checked to remove all code and only apply simple alert on click event, but script not works...what should i do.

Comment: again i test the alert internal script in other subpages like login, about, contact but nothing happens. i also change the library loading, i tried to load jquery from head and main.js from last of page content inside body. also nothing happens.

Comment: is it due to my subpages loading fashion because still i am loading pages inside main-wrapper class.

Comment: @ShahzadAshrafi - I realized, that you have unnacepted my answer only because you have another (not question related) problem. That is **very rude** (you should post another question) and I am leaving my comment here, so others can see how do you behave.

Comment: actuallly, i am a new user, and i don't know how stack overflow works. i accept what you say, i anyone try to help me, i must give him/her a feedback...don't leave to stop your answer here.

Comment: well, is it good to ask new problems because my problem is inter related in comment section, or i need to use a new question for this, or can i ask the new question as cascade style within my question.

Comment: Your original question was about event binding. Your new question is about url/hash changing.
If you ask in comments, nobody gets notified (except me). If you start new question with proper title, it will show up in new question and somebody will notice that there is a question without answer.